# How to get all types in a Go package of specific version?

Tags: go

The "go/importer" package (using the "source" importer) does not work if I give a version of the package I want to import. I am looking for an alternative that does accept package paths with the format: "package@version", and that hopefully uses the same "go/types" for its results.